# I have to create a window service in c#.net. this service runs the msonline command

Tags: c#

I have to create a window service in c#.net. This service runs the msonline command but its failing. The exception is:

> 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Comment: if its a x64 server,copy folder  MSOnline and MSOnline Extended from system32 folder to SysWOW64.If this doesn`t solve,give details of your server.it is 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Thanks for solution. I am searching from two days. what is the reason behind to copy in SysWOW64 folder.

Comment: how to get  MSOnline and MSOnline Extended folder while installing msonline.